# playonlinux installation failed how do I fix it?

Tags: apt, wine, dpkg, playonlinux

So I was installing playonlinux as I wanted iTunes. I typed in the terminal `sudo apt-get install playonlinux` and it went well. But I can't find it on my laptop anywhere. When I try to install it again it says

```
E: Could not get lock /var/lib/dpkg/lock - open (11: Resource temporarily unavailable)
E: Unable to lock the administration directory (/var/lib/dpkg/), is another process using it?
```

Can I delete what has installed of playonlinux and if so, how? Or how do I reinstall it? I'm confused. Thanks

Comment: Try hitting alt+f2 and then typing `playonlinux`.  Does that open Play On Linux for you?  (if so, I'll turn this into an answer, if not it'll stay a comment)

Comment: Nope nothing happens ^^

Comment: Do you have the software center, synaptic, or update manager running right now?

Comment: Errr not that I know of, can I find out in the terminal?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe the installation process was interrupted
Or do you run Synaptic, Software Center or Update Manager at the moment?
Because the apt installer is locked.

If you want to unlock it and you're not running Synaptic or something else, you should take a look here 
[Unable to lock the administration directory (/var/lib/dpkg/) is another process using it?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/15433/how-do-i-fix-a-could-not-get-lock-var-lib-dpkg-lock-problem)

There you find an answer how to unlock apt.

After that, you should be able to use it again and remove or install PlayOnLinux again.

Comment: Okay how do I remove what I've got of playonlinux?

Comment: You can remove PlayOnLinux with the following command `sudo apt-get remove playonlinux`.

Answer (score 0):

This apps  usually lock apt ;

Update
Synaptic
Ubuntu Software center
moun sowftware center

it is secure polity for computer , if they are not open at same time when you trying install and you get this error

[HOW TO FİX DPKG LOCK](https://askubuntu.com/questions/15433/how-do-i-fix-a-could-not-get-lock-var-lib-dpkg-lock-problem)